# Stored procedure in that needs to return unique values in a custom format but seems to return duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server that should return unique values based on a custom format: SSSSTT99999  where SSSS and TT is based on a parameter and 99999 is a unique sequence based on the values of SSSS and TT.  I need to store the last sequence based on SSSS and TT on table so I can retrieve the next sequence the next time.    The problem with this code is that in a multi-user environment, at least two simultaneous calls may generate the same value.  How can I make sure that each call to this stored procedure gets a unique value?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenRef   
    @TT nvarchar(30),   
    @SSSS nvarchar(50)   
AS  
    declare @curseq as integer 
    set @curseq=(select sequence from DocSequence where 
            docsequence.TT=@TT and 
            DocSequence.SSSS=@SSSS)
    if @curseq is null
    begin
        set @curseq=1
        insert docsequence (id,TT,SSSS,sequence) values 
                        (newid(),@TT,@SSSS,1)
    end 
    else
    begin
        update DocSequence set Sequence=@curseq+1 where 
            docsequence.TT=@TT and 
            DocSequence.SSSS=@SSSS
    end
    declare @curtr varchar(30)
    set @curtr=RIGHT('0000' + @SSSS,4) 
        + @TT
        + RIGHT('00000' + @curseq,5)
    select @curtr
GO
```

updated code with transactions:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenTRNum]   
@TRType nvarchar(50),   
@BranchCode nvarchar(50)   
AS  
declare @curseq as integer 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;  
begin transaction 
if not exists (select top 1 sequence from DocSequence where 
        docsequence.DocType=@trtype and 
        DocSequence.BranchCode=@BranchCode) 
begin
    insert docsequence (id,doctype,sequence,branchcode) values 
                    (newid(),@trtype,1,@BranchCode)
end 
else
begin
    update DocSequence set Sequence=sequence+1 where 
        docsequence.DocType=@trtype and 
        DocSequence.BranchCode=@BranchCode 
end
commit
set @curseq=(select top 1 sequence from DocSequence where 
    docsequence.DocType=@trtype and 
    DocSequence.BranchCode=@BranchCode)
declare @curtr varchar(30)
set @curtr=RIGHT('0000' + @BranchCode,4) 
    + @TRType 
    + RIGHT('00000' + convert(varchar(5),@curseq),5)
select @curtr
```

Comment: You can use database transactions

Comment: Thank you Sheraz.  I updated the stored procedure to use transactions (see updated code above).    I created a sample code that has 10 threads launch simultaneously and generating 100 each thread.   The first entry have a sequence  SSSSTT00001 is duplicated several times, and the insert seems to have run several times.  but only 00001 is duplicated, the rest is not.

Comment: @saltedeggchips Sorry, but  your updated SP still have problem with locks. Please publish your table structure includind indexes/PK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this on application level by using threading assuming you have single application Server.

Suppose you have method `GetUniqueVlaue` Which Executes this SP. 
What you should do is use threading. that method use database transactions with [readcommited](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level). Now for example if two users have made the call to `GetUniqueVlaue` method at exactly `2019-08-30 10:59:38.173` time your application will make threads and Each thread will try to open transaction. only one will open that transaction on that SP and other will go on wait.

Comment: unfortunately, the reason why this has to be on a stored procedure is that multiple applications will be using this.  it's not a single application server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve this task:

Table structure, unique indexes are important

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.DocSequence;
CREATE TABLE dbo.DocSequence (
    RowID           INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_DocSequence PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    BranchCode  CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    DocType     CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    SequenceID  INT     NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_DocSequence_SequenceID DEFAULT(1)
        CONSTRAINT CH_DocSequence_SequenceID CHECK (SequenceID BETWEEN 1 AND 999999),
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_DocSequence_BranchCode_DocType 
    ON dbo.DocSequence (BranchCode,DocType) INCLUDE(SequenceID);
GO
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GenTRNum
    @BranchCode VARCHAR(4),
    @DocType    VARCHAR(2),
    --
    @curseq     INT         = NULL OUTPUT,
    @curtr      VARCHAR(30) = NULL OUTPUT
AS

SELECT  @curseq     = NULL,
        @curtr      = NULL,
        @BranchCode = RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',@BranchCode),4),
        @DocType    = RIGHT(CONCAT('00',@DocType),2)

-- Atomic operation, no transaction needed
UPDATE  dbo.DocSequence
SET     @curseq = SequenceID += 1
WHERE   DocType = @DocType
        AND BranchCode = @BranchCode;

IF @curseq IS NULL  -- Not found, create new one
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT  dbo.docsequence (doctype,branchcode)
        SELECT  @DocType, @BranchCode
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.DocSequence WHERE  DocType = @DocType  AND BranchCode = @BranchCode)

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
            BEGIN
                COMMIT;
                SET @curseq = 1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK;

                UPDATE  dbo.DocSequence
                SET     @curseq = SequenceID += 1
                WHERE   DocType = @DocType
                        AND BranchCode = @BranchCode;
            END
END

SET @curtr = @BranchCode + @DocType + RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',@curseq),5)
RETURN
GO
```

I did some tests to make sure is it works as described. You can use it if you need

```
-- Log table just for test
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.GenTRNumLog;
CREATE TABLE dbo.GenTRNumLog(
    RowID       INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    SPID        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Cycle       INT NULL,
    dt          DATETIME NULL,
    sq          INT NULL,
    tr          VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    DurationMS  INT NULL
)
```

This script should be opened in several separate MS SQL Management Studio windows and run they almost simultaneously

```
-- Competitive insertion test, run it in 5 threads simultaneously 
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE
    @dt         DATETIME,
    @start      DATETIME,
    @DurationMS INT,
    @Cycle      INT,
    @BC         VARCHAR(4),
    @DC         VARCHAR(2),
    @SQ         INT,
    @TR         VARCHAR(30); 

SELECT @Cycle = 0,
        @start = GETDATE();

WHILE DATEADD(SECOND, 60, @start) > GETDATE()   -- one minute test, new @DocType every second
BEGIN
    SET @dt = GETDATE();

    SELECT @BC = FORMAT(@dt,'HHmm'),    -- Hours + Minuts as @BranchCode
           @DC = FORMAT(@dt,'ss'),      -- seconds as @DocType
           @Cycle += 1

    EXEC dbo.GenTRNum @BranchCode = @BC, @DocType = @Dc, @curseq = @SQ OUTPUT, @curtr = @TR OUTPUT

    SET @DurationMS = DATEDIFF(ms, @dt, GETDATE());

    INSERT INTO dbo.GenTRNumLog (SPID, Cycle , dt, sq, tr, DurationMS)
    SELECT SPID = @@SPID, Cycle = @Cycle, dt = @dt, sq = @SQ, tr = @TR, DurationMS = @DurationMS

END

/*
Check test results

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DocSequence

SELECT sq = MAX(sq), DurationMS = MAX(DurationMS) 
FROM dbo.GenTRNumLog 

SELECT * FROM dbo.GenTRNumLog 
ORDER BY tr
*/
```